# Can't see timestamps in Apache Kafka 0.10.0.0. RC4

Tags: apache-kafka

Hi I have downloaded Apache Kafka 0.10.0.0. RC4 from [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@kafka.apache.org/msg49581.html), which has the ability now attach timestamps to messages as stated [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-32+-+Add+timestamps+to+Kafka+message).

I have then run it on my server as I normally would and it is receiving logs.

But when I am running the Kafka consumer console to view a topic, the logs look no different and have no timestamp? They are sent to Kafka in JSON would this affect things? Can you see them in the consumer console? IF not where?

I am trying to see how long it takes to get through the first stage of my pipeline.

Answer (score 26):

By default the timestamp is not shown when running the console consumer.  You must enable it via a property setting:

```
# `print.timestamp=true` requires Kafka 0.10.0+
$ kafka-console-consumer.sh --property print.timestamp=true [...]
```

Btw, you may also consider adding `--property print.key=true` so that the console consumer also prints the key of a Kafka message.

Also, the application that writes to Kafka must support the new Kafka 0.10 message format, which includes the new embedded timestamps.  Perhaps you can't see the timestamps because the upstream application/producer never included any.

Comment: Is there anyway to get kafka to add this to logs, so other consumers see them (not just the consumer console)?

Comment: What do you mean?  The newly introduced timestamps (see [KIP-32](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-32+-+Add+timestamps+to+Kafka+message)) are embedded in the actual messages.

Comment: Not in mine it doesn't: Here is what I send to kafka and it hasnt changed: "{"rsyslog_timestamp":"2016-05-18T13:47:45.320916+00:00", "message":"<IP REMOVED> - - 2016-05-18T13:47:45:320824 \"GET \/investing\/shares\/international-diversified-shares?user=user158 HTTP\/1.1\" 301 692"}"

Comment: Which Kafka producer library are you using?  The Java producer that's included in upcoming Kafka 0.10.0.0?

Comment: Rsyslog. It adds a timestamp. But I want want in Kafka to track latency.

Comment: Then perhaps your rsyslog "connector" for Kafka (which produces=writes syslog messages to Kafka) hasn't yet been updated to include the new embedded timestamps.

Comment: Ok then that might make more sense.

Comment: Friendly reminder: you should accept the answer if it did answer your question.

Comment: @colin-SBI: If you are on the CLI, you can pipe the output of the console consumer to another CLI utility for reformatting.  I don't remember off the top of my head whether such re-formatting of timestamps is supported by the console consumer directly (but I think it is not).

Comment: @MichaelG.Noll Thanks.
I came up with the following (not super fast solution) that can be applied to kafka-console-consumer which returns a line like CreateTime:1507932361676 [....]
`./kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic ... --property print.key=true --property print.timestamp=true | awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {if ($1 ~ /^CreateTime.*/) {a=substr($1, 12, length($1)-14); cmd = "date -d @"a" +%F-%H:%M:%S"; cmd | getline dat; close(cmd); $1=""} else {dat = ""}; print dat $0}'

Comment: why can't I see this with kafka-avro-console-consumer